# Stability of the following nonlinear ODE

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-analysis, lyapunov-functions

I want to obtain the necessary condition(s) such that the equilibrium (i.e., $x=-\frac{b}{a}$) of the following nonlinear (single and not a system of) ODE is asymptotically stable.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=e^t (ax+b); a,b \in ℝ$

Can I use the Lyapunov stability theorems? If so, how?
I know that I can solve this specific ODE analytically and then discuss its asymptotic behavior, but suppose that I do not want to solve it.

Comment: Note that $e^t$ does not influence any stability, technically a time change can reduce your equation to $\dot y=ay+b$. Here the full analysis is trivial.

Comment: Note also that you can get an explicit expression of $x(t)$ by separating the variables and integrating.

Comment: @pioneer Thanks. As I said, suppose that I cannot solve this ODE. I want to use some theorems regarding convergence or asymptotical stability.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. what you can do is the following:
1) Translate your equilibrium point to the origin
2) Use the Lyapunov function $V(x)=x^2$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it seems obvious that the 1st-order system is asymptotically stable when

$$a < 0,$$

because $b$ can be treated as an external input.

Let $a = - \alpha$, where $\alpha > 0$, then the solution is given by

$$x(t) = \frac{\alpha x_{0} - b}{\alpha} e^{\alpha - \alpha e^{t}} + \frac{b}{\alpha}.$$

where $x_{0}$ is the initial value. If we set $\alpha = 1$, then the solution becomes simply

$$x(t) = \left(x_{0} - b\right) e^{1 - e^{t}} + b.$$